# How to integrate React app into Wordpress (react router)?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-router, react-router-dom

I've created a react app to embed to wordpress site.
React app is created by create-react-app and after bundling, I've uploaded it to wordpress site.
Then created a page to load the bundled js file. (following this guide https://medium.com/@CodeCareerCoach/react-app-inside-a-wordpress-page-or-post-4c7d38181b3d)

So it shows the react app and works for the base route.

When I navigate, it still works, when I refresh I get 404 ERR.

This is the routing of react app.

```
  return <BrowserRouter basename='/testweb'>
    <Layout menuItems={menuItems} pages={pages}>
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <div>okay</div>} />
          <Route exact path="/home" render={(props) => {
              return <div>asdf</div>
            }} 
          />
...
          <Route render={(props)=> props.location.pathname } />
      </Switch>
    </Layout>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

in package.json, I've set `homepage` to `/testweb`
How can I get the nested routes working?

Comment: you should keep in mind that you have `air-doc` prefix, without it, it should work. Try `path="/air-doc/home" `

Comment: @blits, I've edited the question, I set basename to `/air-doc`, so I think there's no problem with this.

Comment: exact only on the root ?

Comment: @milosh-n, Yes. works only for the root.

Comment: Try to remove **exact** from '/home' path?

Comment: @MiloshN. It can't be a problem I think.

Comment: @XiaoJin, I am not sure, but I think **exact** must be on the '/' root of the project.

Comment: @MiloshN, Just tried, not working yet. same result

Comment: @think-serious, why is return here in arrow fun? Arrow fun will return it...

Comment: @MiloshN. Not a problem - works fine on local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer. Please share a better one if you have.

Let's say our app's name is testweb.

- First, changed homepage attribute in package.json to another,
  testweb-react.
- Kept the routing as it is(using testweb as base url).
- Uploaded    build files to root of wordpress site.
- Created          /testweb/.htaccess file to internally redirect to
  testweb-react

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ – [L]
RewriteRule ^ /testweb-react/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps others also!